# Installing Sage 6 and opening it on windows 8 PC with 64 bit

Tags: python, installation, sage

This question is mainly about installation of Sage, but I figured I'd give here a try: also in general I'm a bit confused regarding installation of Sage:

I went to the download page, after choosing the server close to my location:

sage-6.1.1.tar.gz

and downloaded it to my windows 8, 64-bit PC. However, the file is not opening (I double clicked on it in order to run it) in my PC, even after installing 7-zip, with which I could extract/convert it to a .tar file. What is your suggestion for opening it and getting Sage to work? I thought that its installation would be as simple as that of python itself, where I did not run into a opening/running problem.

Apologies if this is an irrelevant question for this site!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not irrelevant at all, but you didn't read the instructions for Windows.  Currently there is only a virtualization option - one which is pretty popular, from what I can tell.

[Here is one mirror that might be near you](http://mirrors.xmission.com/sage/win/index.html), and note it says

```
Please read the Sage Virtual Machine manual.
```

Short version - you download VirtualBox and the .ova file, and that starts things off.

I'm not sure why the VM version hasn't been updated to 6.1.1 yet, and I'll ask about that.

Edit: see [this link on the sage-release list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sage-release/NO_XQz5djfk) where the updated ova files are hot off the presses!

Comment: I should also point out there is no need to install anything on Windows... the Sage math cloud or Sage notebook work with any non-ancient browser!

Comment: kcrisman: it seems to me so too, but in order to save the program, can I still use Sage math cloud or Sage notebook? I'M using Sage notebook for the tutorials given on Sage's webpage, but the command are NOT changing colors when I type them on Sage notebook. Any reason why? Any suggestion to resolve this?

Comment: Also, I'm facing a problem when I open sage (my version is 5.13), two windows are popping up: one is Oracle VM virtualBox Manager, another is asking me to import virtual appliance, gives me appliance settings and a list of name, product, product URL, version, vendor, guest OS type.....etc. How can I open the Sage page? I was expecting I could open the sage just like python!

Comment: Again, I think the virtual machine manual should ask these questions.  Because Sage relies not just on Python, but a host of specialized mathematics tools which do not play well with Windows (or perhaps one should say the other way around...) we do need this virtualization solution at this time for local running.  It's possible that one of the cloud solutions will be more effective for you.

Comment: The Sage notebook doesn't have syntax highlighting.  However, https://cloud.sagemath.com worksheets *do* have syntax highlighting.